# C snprintf sprintf stack smashing detected

Tags: c

I have the following function which will hit "stack smashing detected" sometimes. But when I modify `sprintf()` to `snprintf(nbytes_buf, sizeof(nbytes_buf), "%d", nbytes)`, the problem is solved.

'data' will never be larger than 1024 bytes. So, I think nbytes_buf[20] is sufficient. But I also hit "stack smashing detected" problem when 'data' contains character '>'.

Does anyone know why?

```
int a( const char *data )
{
    int nbytes;
    char nbytes_buf[20];

    nbytes = strlen(data);
    sprintf(nbytes_buf, "%d", nbytes);

    /* do something else */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If modified to be as you say, `snprintf(nbytes_buf, sizeof(nbytes_buf), nbytes)`, you're passing `nbytes` as the address of the format string, which obviously isn't right. Perhaps `snprintf(nbytes_buf, sizeof(nbytes_buf), "%d", nbytes)` would be more constructive. **Edit**: or change the code in the question. That works too.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected.

Comment: Are you using exactly this format string, types and everything in your real code?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sprintf()` The size of the buffer should be large enough to contain the entire resulting string. snprintf() will overcome this problem because If the resulting string is longer than **n-1** characters, the remaining characters are discarded and not stored.

So you are getting the error `"stack smashing detected"` only when you use `sprintf()` and the size of the string is greater than `n-1`. If you use `snprintf()` the problem will not occur even if the size of the string is greater than `n-1`.

Comment: How would a "%d" create a result longer than the 20 characters he has preallocated?

Comment: Yes Jerry, I have created 20 characters array nbytes_buf[20]. I think it is sufficient for my application that 'data' will not be too long.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah reaching 10000000000000000000, i.e. 0x8AC7230489E80000 is doable with a 64bit `size_t` but I really want this guy's machine if it can handle, much less *has*, strings that large.

Answer (score 0):

read http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/printf.html
The snprintf() function shall be equivalent to sprintf(), with the addition of the n argument which states the size of the buffer referred to by s. If n is zero, nothing shall be written and s may be a null pointer. Otherwise, ***output bytes beyond the n-1st shall be discarded instead of being written to the array, a***nd a null byte is written at the end of the bytes actually written into the array.